# Random sample in bigquery gives inconsistent results

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using the `RAND` function in bigquery to provide me with a random sample of data, and unioning it with another sample of the same dataset. 
This is for a machine learning problem where I'm interested in one class more than the other.

I've recreated the logic using a public dataset.

```
SELECT
COUNT(1),
bigarticle
FROM
(
  SELECT 
  1 as [bigarticle]
  FROM [bigquery-public-data:samples.wikipedia]
  WHERE num_characters > 50000
  ),
  (
  SELECT 
  0 as [bigarticle]
  FROM [bigquery-public-data:samples.wikipedia]
  WHERE (is_redirect is null) AND (RAND() < 0.01)
  )

GROUP BY bigarticle
```

Most of the time this behaves as expected,
giving one row with the count of rows where `num_characters` is more than 50k,
and giving another row with a count of a 1% sample of rows where `is_redirect` is null.
(This is an approximation of the logic I use in my internal dataset).

If you run this query repeatedly, occasionally it gives unexpected results.
In this result set (`bquijob_124ad56f_15da8af982e`) I only get a single row, containing the count of `bigarticle` = 1.

Comment: Can you calculate probability of rand not being less than 0.01 for that set of data and correlate it with what you named occasionally ? :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RAND` does not use a deterministic seed. If you want deterministic results, you need to hash/fingerprint a column in the table and use a modulus to select a subset of values instead. Using legacy SQL:

```
#legacySQL
SELECT
  COUNT(1),
  bigarticle
FROM (
  SELECT
    1 as [bigarticle]
  FROM [bigquery-public-data:samples.wikipedia]
  WHERE num_characters > 50000
), (
  SELECT 
    0 as [bigarticle]
  FROM [bigquery-public-data:samples.wikipedia]
  WHERE (is_redirect is null) AND HASH(title) % 100 = 0
)
GROUP BY bigarticle;
```

Using standard SQL in BigQuery, which is recommended since legacy SQL is not under active development:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  COUNT(*),
  bigarticle
FROM (
  SELECT
    1 as bigarticle
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.wikipedia`
  WHERE num_characters > 50000
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    0 as bigarticle
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.wikipedia`
  WHERE (is_redirect is null) AND MOD(FARM_FINGERPRINT(title), 100) = 0
)
GROUP BY bigarticle;
```

Comment: Using standard SQL seems to solve the problem. I'll move over to that.